# AKS Container Insights Adjust Agent Run Interval

Tags: azure-aks

I enabled Container Insights for Azure Kubernetes Services
I want to change the run interval for the OMS agent defined in the `omsagent-rs-config` file. I got the template from here : https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/incubator/azuremonitor-containers/templates/omsagent-rs-configmap.yaml

What have I tried :

1. I created a ConfigMap file
2. used `kubectl -f apply configMap.yml` where I essentially changed the log_level to info and run_interval to 10 min

```
     <source>
      type kubepodinventory
      tag oms.containerinsights.KubePodInventory
      run_interval 600
      log_level info
     </source>
```

4. I deleted the omsagent pods and which caused them to be recreated.
5. However my changes to the config map get overridden

How should I go about so that my changed stick.

---

### update : why the manual changes don't stick

1. I noticed that the config-map is annotated with `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile` which as defined here https://fossies.org/linux/kubernetes/cluster/addons/addon-manager/README.md provides an explanation why it gets overridden. However I still need to understand the official way to update this